# Magento 2.4 installation using composer MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Plugin.php failed to open stream: No such file or directory), rolling back

Tags: magento2, composer

I am trying to install Magento2.4 Open source on the following setup.

VirtualBox 6.1 on Windows 10

Nginx server

Ubuntu 20.4 server installed on the Virtualbox

Php  7.3.20

**Command used**:

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .`

I have given 0777 permission to /var/www/html/qa.magento.com/ directory

**I am getting following error**

`Plugin installation failed (include(/var/www/html/qa.magento.com/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), rolling back`

**Detailed Error**:

```
muk@muk:/var/www/html/qa.magento.com$ composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "./"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.0)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.0): Loading from cache
Created project in /var/www/html/qa.magento.com/.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 526 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13): Loading from cache
Plugin installation failed (include(/var/www/html/qa.magento.com/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), rolling back
  - Removing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13)


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /var/www/html/qa.magento.com/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon:


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Following `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/` command is not changing the ownership.

**Update**:
All the above works if I use Ubuntu Server 18.04 instead of Ubuntu Server 20.04

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to install 2.4 and I didn't get such error, however I change `.` to a valid directory name. Please try following:-

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2.4
```

**UPDATE:**

if above didn't work for you, make sure your file/dir permissions are correct. chmod your main directory to 755, and 777 is never a good idea. Also make sure that your magento (web) user belongs to your web server group.

For more information please read:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: I have already tried it but it did not work

Comment: @Mukesh i have update my answer

Comment: The process I have mentioned works fine on the Ubuntu 18.4, Apache server and Php 7.2 version in the VirtualBox.

Comment: delete everything, follow all the steps from scratch from this documentation. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html

Comment: I have done this successfully with Apace server, Ubuntu 18.04 and Php7.2 version, but not sure why it is not working on current VM setup.

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears to be a permissions issue (based on the fact that Composer can't delete the directory *it created* during cleanup after bailing out).

This appears to be stemming from the fact that the `/var/www/html` folder is shared to the host OS. When this happens, the permissions are applied to a directory at boot and can't be changed after-the-fact.

Comment: Everything work well if I use Ubuntu 18.04 server  instead of Ubuntu 20.04 server !

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with a Ubuntu VM, while Hyper-V was turned on in Windows 10. This fixed it:

Open Powershell as administrator and run:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Then restart Windows 10.